# Передать по значению, а не по ссылке Unity3d C#

Tags: c#, unity3d

При масштабировании спрайта мы используем в формуле сам этот спрайт.

```
 //Идет присвоение в методе, без этого никак - у нас не один спрайт.  
    backStationaryCircle = back;
 //Берем координаты правой верхней и левой нижней точки спрайта,вычитая их - получаем размер
    var radiusX = (back.CurrentSprite.positions[3].x - back.CurrentSprite.positions[0].x)/2;
    var radiusY = (back.CurrentSprite.positions[3].y - back.CurrentSprite.positions[0].y)/2;
//Меняем размер спрайта
     backStationaryCircle.scale = new Vector3(((workZoneInPixX / back.scale.x) / radiusX), ((workZoneInPixY / back.scale.y) / radiusY), 0.001f);
```

И при следующей итерации работаем с измененным размером спрайта. А оно нам не нужно, нужно чтобы мы просто взяли значения размера спрайта изначально и использовали его как переменную, уже независимо от того, как оно меняется в ходе преобразования.

Comment: Непонятно, что мешает вам работать непосредственно со значениями размеров

Comment: хз, может иметь, например, словарь `Dictionary<GameObject, float>` в котором ссылка на объект и первоначальный размер. Объект появляется - добавляется в него, уничтожается - убивается и из словаря тоже.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Всё, как всегда, проще чем кажется. Снимаем изначальные значения в методе Start(); или любом другом, который вызывается только 1 раз. Затем уже используем их как захотим - снятые один раз, они не меняются.